# Is there any way of specifying the Id property name when inheriting or implementing AuditedAggregateRoot or Entity in ABP.IO?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

Recently I was faced with modernizing a legacy application, while also keeping the old database structure, I thought of using ABP.IO in, general I'd say it was a good decision, the framework is great. But in some cases, the old database tables' Id was either a string or int, but with a name other than Id, this becomes problematic when trying to implement either `AuditedAggregateRoot` or `Entity` in the entity class to get all the cool stuff that you get to do when implementing either or those, like using the CrudService and so on.

I looked all over the documentation and couldn't find any refence on how to accomplish this, using another property name, but perhaps I'm just not that good at searching, so any input regarding this would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: why don't you add Id fields if there's no

Comment: Because there is a primary key, its just not named 'Id'.